# PDF Page break and Adding footer line

Tags: pdf, table

Hi please help me how to fix this
[image]

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
                @page {
                margin-left: 1cm;
                margin-right: 1cm;
                margin-top: 0.8cm;
                margin-bottom: 2cm;
                                @bottom-center {                 
                content: element(footer);              
                }

                @top-center {
                content: element(header);

                }
                }

                table {
                              page-break-inside: avoid; 

                }
                div.footer { 
                             page-break-after: avoid;
                display: block;              
                position:running(footer);
                font-size:12px;
                font-family:" sans-serif";
                }
                div.header {
                display: block;                     
                position: running(header);
                }
                            </style>
```

if i add "   -fs-table-paginate: paginate;" to table in style sheet
footer line is vanishing in all pages except first page.

Please help me on fixing this

Comment: Because this is native CSS, I think this question is more suited for stackoverflow .

Comment: I disagree. I think there are enough Salesforce-specific quirks to rendering visualforce as a pdf that it's still appropriate here.